# Throttle download traffic in apache for all users

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver

Lets say I subdomain called largefiles.domain.com
This is on a dedicated server and I can change any configuration. 
Server runs Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

How do i restrict all file downloads to just 10Kbps for every file downloaded from the webserver? What is the easiest solution to implement this for the entire subdomain?

Comment: I think this is more suited for serverfault.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i guess following Pieter's suggestions. I get much more response from serverfault.

Thanks.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/25859/throttle-download-traffic-in-apache-for-all-users